# Change the "id" attribute onclick

Tags: onclick, toggleclass

I'd like to change the "id" of an image (instead of toggleclass, because the class is already being used) like this :

```
<img src="<?php echo HTTP_IMAGES_PATH; ?>roof.png" class="img-responsive" id="roof" />
<button onclick="changeID('roof_red')">RED</button>
```

with the javascript part :

```
function changeID(this_color) {
        $('roof').attr('id', this_color);
        console.log(this_color);
    }
```

And the HTML :

```
<button onclick="changeID('roof_red')">RED</button>
```

It is not working and when I look at the log, there's a reference error : $ is not defined... What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like jQuery didn't load correctly.  Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2195167/5166082) troubleshooting help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that if you want to use jQuery (making an educated guess...) you have to include it in the page. probably missing some `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` or a variant of this.

Regarding what you're doing wrong, well, there's little to no good reason to change an element ID, and not manipulating CSS classes or attributes is definitely not a good reason.

Comment: Yes, the jquery.js was missing. I can see the console.log now, but the ID still doesn't change...

Comment: I answered that part as well. You should use CSS to control styles, not modify IDs for that.

Comment: But it's not an answer to my question. I asked how to change the id value of the img tag with javascript.

Comment: @dujmovicv - I advise you to read [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (That's not an answer to your specific question, but it's important that you understand this concept). After that read my answer and earlier comment again. I **strongly** recommend you not to try changing the ID.